# Cordova run android is taking forever to install app on device

Tags: android, cordova

Ok, I have created and run various Cordova apps in the past, but since the last 2 weeks I have more and more issues with getting any app to install on my device. I have an LGE975 (LG Optimus G) phone, and there are already 5 Cordova apps installed on it.

Sometimes if I just try it 20 times it will work. Today however I have tried to run apps I don't know how many times, but they just won't install, and no error is thrown.

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstalling Cordova
- Upgrading cordova from 3.1.0-0.1.0 to -0.2.0
- Downgrading back to -0.1.0
- Rebooting device
- Rebooting pc

`Running app on platform "android" via command "cmd" /c C:\CordovaProjects\HelloW
orld\platforms\android\cordova\run --device
Buildfile: C:\CordovaProjects\HelloWorld\platforms\android\build.xml`

What is it doing during the installation on device? The verbose output of Cordova isn't showing much of where it could go wrong. Also no error is thrown.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comment aboive i just runned:

```
platforms\android\cordova\run --device
```

and it worked!

It must be a bug or something.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it worked when I launched the process from an Administrator command prompt.

(On windows 7, Start -> Search Programs and Files -> type "cmd" -> Right-click on CMD -> Run as Administrator -> run phonegap command)

Comment: Thx. In my experience it just works sometimes, and sometimes not. However, in 99% of the cases where `cordova run` doesn't work. You can try to go to the platform/android/ folder and do `cordova\run --device` directly. Don't ask me why, but this solved the problem in 99% of the cases.

Comment: What could be a logical explanation for this behaviour? Running Cordova as Administrator solved my issues as well. The building process gets now done in 12 seconds (instead of 2 Minutes and 42 Seconds)

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a 'duh' answer, but maybe its an android version update that was applied to your device (phone) and the OS is now slowing things down?

Or, maybe your device is really full on storage space, and you should free up some space to speed things up :)